# Screen doesn't recognize Firebase auth errors - where is the problem?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a log in screen set up and I wanted to add alerts for when the email is invalid, for when the password is weak and for when they don't match. This is what I have:

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const incompleteForm = !email || !password
  const [invalidEmail, setInvalidEmail] = useState(false);
  const [wrongPassword, setWrongPassword] = useState(false);

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleLogIn = () => {

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(userCredentials => {
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      navigation.replace('Navigation')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.code == "auth/weak-password") {
        setTimeout(() => {
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        'The password must be 6 characters long or more',
        [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Login')}],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
    }, 100);
  }
  else if (error.code == "auth/invalid-email") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        'The email address is not valid',
        [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Login')}],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
    }, 100);
  }
  else if (error.code == "auth/wrong-password") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        'Incorrect email or password',
        [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Login')}],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
    }, 100);
  }
})
  }

 return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style = {styles.container} behavior = 'padding'>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/pop1.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </View>
      
  <View style = {styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput 
      placeholder = 'Email'
      value = {email}
      onChangeText = {text => setEmail(text)}
      autoCapitalize = 'none'
      autoCorrect = {false}
    />
    <TextInput 
      value = {password}
      onChangeText = {text => setPassword(text)}
      secureTextEntry
      autoCapitalize = 'none'
      autoCorrect = {false}
    />
  </View>

  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {handleLogIn}
   disabled = {incompleteForm}>
      <Text>Log in</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>

</KeyboardAvoidingView>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

For some reason I only get the alert for the invalid username error and not for the other two and I can't figure it out since the same alert I have for the weak password works perfectly fine on another sign up screen I have. Where is the problem?

This is the working code on the sign up screen:

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const incompleteForm = !email || !password

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSignUp = async() => {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(userCredentials => { 
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      navigation.navigate('Setup');
    })
.catch((error) => {
  if (error.code == "auth/email-already-in-use") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        'The email address is already in use',
        [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Signup')}],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
    }, 100);
  }
  else if (error.code == "auth/invalid-email") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        'The email address is not valid',
        [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Signup')}],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
    }, 100);
  } else if (error.code == "auth/weak-password") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          'The password must be 6 characters long or more',
          [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Signup')}],
          {cancelable: false},
        );
      }, 100);
  }
})
  }

  return (
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior = 'padding'>
  <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" translucent={true} />

  <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
    <Image source={require('../assets/pop.png')}/>
  </View>       
  <View style = {styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput 
      placeholder = 'Email'
      value = {email}
      onChangeText = {text => setEmail(text)}
      autoCapitalize = 'none'
      autoCorrect = {false}
    />
    <TextInput 
      placeholder = 'Password'
      value = {password}
      onChangeText = {text => setPassword(text)}
      secureTextEntry
      autoCapitalize = 'none'
      autoCorrect = {false}
    />
  </View>

  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {handleSignUp} disabled = {incompleteForm}>
      <Text>Sign up</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

Comment: Maybe you'd like to show the working code as well so it would be easier for us to spot the difference between them, if there is any.

Comment: I've included the working code as well!

Answer (score 0):

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` doesn't generate the codes you're looking for, but `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` does.  If the user already has an account that was created with the latter, Firebase doesn't need to check the password for weakness, and it doesn't need to check the email address for validity.  The error Firebase needs to worry about with signing in is whether or not they got the password right, and it's not going to tell you if the email exists or not because that would be a security problem.

All that said, the code seems to be working fine.  Just remove the error conditions that won't happen.

Comment: I've removed the weak password and invalid email alerts from the log in page but it's still not recognizing the wrong password alert. Is there anything I could try to do about it?

Comment: So what **is** the code you're getting?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Log the code you're getting - what is it, if not the string you expect?

Comment: Also I will point out that `auth/wrong-password` isn't a valid code according to the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

Comment: It doesn't log anything, it's acting as if I'm not pressing the button at all, that's what's so confusing to me. I found the documentation here: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes)

Comment: That's not something we can help you with.  You're going to have to do some debugging to figure out what is happening.  This involves logging or step-through debugging to trace the execution of code.

Comment: I figured it out, it was sending too many requests for the email I was testing it with, I wasn't logging it at the proper place in the code so I couldn't see the mistake. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.